# Certificates - api or sobject access

Tags: apex, crypto

I use [Crypto](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_crypto.htm) class to sign some data with certificate. The method signWithCertificate(algorithmName, input, certDevName) uses the certificate name.

Now I am coding the admin page which will allow admin select one of the certificates from the key store.

Is there a way to retrieve list of certificate names? 
Is there an API to work with keystore?
Is it possible to soql query for certificate names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there is no way to query the available certificates in Apex, the Partner API, or the Tooling API.

They are exposed in the [Metadata API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_certificate.htm), but don't seem to have a field that corresponds to the developer name for the certificate. The `masterLabel` is most likely the value you need. You might be able to use the [Apex Wrapper Salesforce Metadata API](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi) with a listMetadata API call and `type_x` of `certs`.

For what it's worth, certificates have the keyprefix [0P1](http://www.fishofprey.com/2011/09/obscure-salesforce-object-key-prefixes.html#0P1). You could potentially screen scrape them from /0P1. I'd avoid this if you can, as it would be very prone to breaking.

Comment: Pump the brakes! Brittle solution prone to braking! Haha.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Ha, you got me :). Screen scraping could certainly slow you down like brakes. I'm trying to figure out how "Braking Changes" would relate "Breaking Changes."

Comment: If Metadata API can do this, then there is probably a way to query it from Metadata tables. Thanks for the hint with type_x=certs, will give it a try